# Wrong when passing a multidimensional array to an function which passing it to another function in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Im trying to create a multidimensional array with random values that only occur once.

```
void fillRows(int m, int n, int r[m][n]) {
  time_t t;
  srand((unsigned)time(&t));

  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

      temp = 1;
      while (temp == 1) {
        r[i][j] = (rand() % 35 + 1);
        printf(" r[i][j] = %d ,", r[i][j]);

        if (alreadyInRow(m, n, r, r[i][j]) != 1) {
          temp = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int alreadyInRow(int k, int l, int ra[k][l], int e) {
  printf("hej! ,");
  printf("e = %d ,", e);
  for (int n = 0; n <= l; n++) {
    printf(" ra[i][j] = %d ", ra[k][n]);
    if (ra[k][n] == e) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int rows[3][7] = {
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}};
  fillRows(3, 7, rows);
}
```

But when I run the code I get the following:

```
"r[i][j] = 4 ,hej! ,e = 4 , ra[i][j] = 32767, ra[i][j] = 423166060  ra[i][j] = 1536635611  ra[i][j] = 1550322336  ra[i][j] = 32767  ra[i][j] = -814317003  ra[i][j] = 32767  ra[i][j] = 0  r[i][j] = 26 ,hej! ,e = 26 , ra[i][j] = 32767  ra[i][j] = 423166060  ra[i][j] = 1536635611  ra[i][j] = 1550322336  ra[i][j] = 32767  ra[i][j] = -814317003  ra[i][j] = 32767  ra[i][j] = 0  r[i][j] = 28, etc etc etc"
```

So it seems like when i pass the array from the function fillRows() to the function isAlreadyInRow() the array doesnt follow?

Comment: Inside `alreadyInRow`, what value(s) does `k` take? Is it a valid index?

Comment: Useless, nice! k took the wrong value. It took the m value instead of the i value.

Comment: first try to have something that compile.

Comment: @Stargateur it does compile

Comment: @JuliusHopf http://rextester.com/FAZDY15138

Comment: @Stargateur this is just 1.) pointless warnings about VLAs, 2.) missing `#include`s (yes, OP should add them for MCVE) and 3.) missing declaration of `temp`, obviously a global. Only 3.) is "bad", it should really be a local.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I don't care, why should I take time to answer a question where OP didn't take time to create a [mcve] that COMPILE. But if this question is OK for you, answer it.

Comment: @Stargateur MCVE isn't strictly required to compile as-is and the missing includes are more than obvious. Well, you took time writing comments ;)

Comment: ` printf(" ra[i][j] = %d ", ra[k][n]);` is printing outside the array. `k` is one dimension of the array. if you want that last dim you need `k-1`. I think you need to loop over both dims. plus you do `<= l` you mean `<l`. C array indexes start at 0

Comment: @FelixPalmen I disagree, For question about "why is this not working", yes a [mcve] must compile. This question is not about "how to do that" in this case yes the code could not compile.

Comment: Function signature should be something like `int alreadyInRow(int row, int l, int ra[][l], int e)`

Comment: @Stargateur well, the definition of a MCVE doesn't require that. It requires completeness: "*Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included*" and well, only using standard library functions is arguably *complete*, it's just *nicer* for people trying to reproduce it to already include the relevant `#include`s.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this function:

```
int alreadyInRow(int k, int l, int ra[k][l], int e) {
    // [...]
    if (ra[k][n] == e)
    // [...]
}
```

You are passing `k` as the number of rows, and then try to access `ra[k][n]` which is an element in the `k+1`th row, it's an access *out of bounds*.

From the name of the function, you only want to check elements in the *current row*. You **can** use the parameter `k` for that, because there's no need to pass the *first* dimension of a variable-length array. Just passing your current row for `k` when calling this function will work, but it's conceptually wrong because your code will read as if the array only has `k` rows. But if you change the signature like this:

```
int alreadyInRow(int k, int l, int ra[][l], int e)
```

(note `k` isn't used any more as a dimension), it will be correct.

Still, I suggest you start using **meaningful** variable and parameter names, they help yourself when searching for errors as well as others reading and understanding your code. I would suggest something like this:

```
int alreadyInRow(int cols, int array[][cols], int row, int element)
```

---

Finally, if you just want to check a single row, there's no need to pass a pointer to your whole 2d array, a pointer to a single row would be enough, so your function could look simply like this:

```
int alreadyInRow(int *array, int col, int element) {
  for (int n = 0; n < col; ++n) {
    if (array[n] == element) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You would call it like this from your other function:

```
if (alreadyInRow(r[i], j, r[i][j]) != 1)
```